# Como inserir um novo valor dentro array sem duplicar através do switch case?

Tags: javascript, array, switch

Uma de minhas tentativas até o momento foi:

```js
array = [1, 2, 4, 5];

definir = function() {
    switch (array) {

        case (array > 1):
            array.push(1);
            break;

        case (array > 2):
            array.push(2);
            break;

        case (array > 0):
            array.push(3);
            break;
    }

    // Comparar elementos duplicado dentro de um vetor
    var checar = array.filter(function(valor, i) {
        return array.indexOf(valor) == i;
    })

    alert(checar);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="definir();">Definir e Verificar</button>
```

Estou procurando incluir novos elementos que esteja dentro de uma opção `case` no `array`.

Mas antes verificar se no `array` encontra-se o mesmo elemento, para evitar duplicar!

Comment: Por que é necessário o Switch?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Experimento em um projeto pessoal, nada de mais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta apenas checar se o valor obtido não existe na coleção (como o título já diz), então puxá-lo diretamente nela.

A sua verificação do `checar` parece estar errada. Esse código fará o mesmo objetivo do seu, exceto que vai evitar duplicar a adição de valores existentes.

Edit: agora que sei seu objetivo de teste, as condições do switch tornaram-se desnecessárias.

```
var array = [1, 2, 4, 5];
var valor = 3;

var existe = array.indexOf(valor) >= 0;
if (existe) {
  alert('O número ' + valor + ' já existe na coleção.');
  // return
} else {
  array.push(valor);
}
// !existe && array.push(valor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depois de algumas repostas dada tanto pelo [Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor-stafusa), seguido do colega [handoncloud](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/37626/handoncloud), cheguei a conclusão final.

Vejamos como checar se o valor existe na coleção do `array` antes mesmo de inserir diretamente nele o novo elemento.

Essa função `array.pop()` fará o objetivo de evitar duplicar a adição de valores existentes.

```js
array = [];

function definir(valor) {
    switch (valor) {
     case '':
      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Nenhum valor informado';
      break;
     default:
      array.push(valor);
      break;
}

     if (valor != array.length) {
      alert('O número ' + valor + ' já existe na coleção.');
      array.pop(valor);
    }

     document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Coleção: ' + array + '<br>Quantidade de valores: ' + array.length

}
```

```html
    <select id="" onchange="definir(this.value);">
        <option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    
    <br/>
    
    <span id="txt">Nenhum valor informado</span>
```

**w3schools** - [Demonstração externa](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCO36AC1LW1H)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro que usar o `switch` assim não é boa ideia. Em geral, o `switch` é algo que tende a ser facilmente usado de maneira inadequada e na maioria das vezes há algum recurso melhor, são poucos os casos onde o `switch` é a melhor alternativa.

Entretanto, se você realmente quer insistir em usar o `switch`, acho que você quer é selecionar o tamanho do array com ele. E portanto o que você quer é isso:

```js
array = [1, 2, 4, 5];

definir = function() {

    switch (array.length) {

        case 1:
            array.push(1);
            break;

        default:
            array.push(2);
            break;

        case 0:
            array.push(3);
            break;
    }

    // Comparar elementos duplicado dentro de um vetor
    var checar = array.filter(function(valor, i) {
        return array.indexOf(valor) == i;
    });
    alert(checar);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="definir();">Definir e Verificar</button>
```

Para demonstrar que o `switch` quase sempre pode ser substituído por algo mais simples, observe que o meu `switch` inteiro poderia ser substituído por isso:

```js
array.push([3, 1, 2][array.length > 2 ? 2 : array.length]);
```